# Kotlin 5.21 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have imported an existing Maven project into IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2. The Maven project uses Kotlin version 1.5.21. However, I get a warning that the version in Maven is incompatible with the version of the IntelliJ plugin, which is 1.5.10 and is the latest available. Is there a way to use Kotlin 1.5.21 in the latest version of IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update to the newest version of Kotlin plugin on 2021.2 for now. See - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18848

Answer (score 1):

Try Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Kotlin > Update channel > Early Access Preview 1.5.x

I don't think the difference in version really matters, but this might be interesting for you.